# signalR generating different ID for various instances

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have created web chat application using signalR. When user is logged in, user can open only 3-4 tabs and each time different connection ID is generated. I want that when we open new tab or refresh the page  new connection id should not be generated. I want to use the existing connection id. For that I tried to implement the LocalStorage variable to store the hub connection.
But Problem is i am unable to parse the value of localstorage variable.

Can Anyone give me the solution to my problem or can anyone give me any other solution to the problem?

I have already tried this http://kevgriffin.com/maintaining-signalr-connectionids-across-page-instances/ but it dosen't work for me

Answer (score 0):

If user is authenticated you can store different connectionIds in the HashSet. The key for the HashSet will be the user's name.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections

You can use this method even if you are not authenticated. In this case you can use SessionId instead of username.

**EDITED**:

I have found another method. In this [article](http://www.codetunnel.com/cannot-have-many-tabs-open-with-signalr/) Alex Ford advices to limit your connections to 3.

Comment: The problem will again be same as different connection ID will be generated and again 3-4 tabs will be opened I want to generate same connection ID. Do you have any idea about this??

Comment: I don't see the problem. Let user "Foo" has 4 different connectionIds (1, 2, 3, 4). All this identifiers stored in the HashSet (which is value of the Dictionary) by key "Foo". If you want to send a message for him you can do following:
Clients.Clients(_connections["foo"]).SendMessage("a message");

Comment: Problem is not with sending message problem is with the connection limit of the browser.

Comment: @Priya, but your question is about different connectionIds in different tabs. Yes, for every tab another connectionId. Most modern browsers has limit for concurrent connections to the same domain. For more information you can read this article: http://sgdev-blog.blogspot.sg/2014/01/maximum-concurrent-connection-to-same.html