# Increase Number of Concurrent Connection Using SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

Hi I am using Signal R on my master page for the chat implementation in a popup like Facebook on right side. but when i open more that 6 tabs other tabs are not opening due to the browser limitation about the ~6 concurrent connections.

SO can any body help how can i do this because i need the connection on every tab so that i can send the chat message.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps [this][1] answer will help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724202/signalr-and-browser-connection-limit

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25692155/1277458

Comment: @Ruchira this is not the case i need the connection because i have to send the messages from each and every page

Comment: @Neshta , connectionID is different so it will not open the connection on next tabs

Comment: @Neshta can i have the Singal Connection on all the tabs?

Comment: @G.S Bhangal, No, because of most modern browsers have a limit on the concurrent connections to the same domain. You can read more this http://sgdev-blog.blogspot.sg/2014/01/maximum-concurrent-connection-to-same.html

Comment: @Neshta Thanks for the information ...SO then aby idea how can I keep working the chat on all the tabs

Comment: A trick, that I believe Facebook also uses, would be to create multiple sub domains than points to the same server, so the browser thinks it's connecting to different servers.

Comment: @Tobias Should i have to create the Hub class on each domain and supply the path to my chat application randomly?